# Check Constraint Seems to be Auto Rounding

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, rounding

I am relatively new to Oracle and seem to be doing something dumb. I'm trying to add a constraint that if my value TestLengthHours are more than 6, attempting to insert a new row should result in an error.

I've had some difficulty explaining what this is to Google and was hoping you fine folks could help tell me my silly mistake.

I'm nearly certain that this has something to do with rounding. If I make TestLengthHours 6.5 or higher, the insert fails as it is intended. If TestLengthHours is anything less than 6.5, it does not.

In my example, I alter the table, TESTTABLE, to add the constraint. I make sure that TestLengthHours <= 6.0 and that TestLengthHours is not null.

Then I attempt to insert a value that *should* fail because it has a TestLengthHours value of 6.1, which is more than 6, and thus should violate the constraint. Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong and the row is being created successfully.

```
-- Constraint for TESTTABLE to make sure TestLengthHours is less than or equal to 6
ALTER TABLE TESTTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT valueTuest
    CHECK (TestLengthHours <= 6.0
    AND TestLengthHours IS NOT NULL);
-- The following insert should fail, but does not, even though 6.1 is more than or equal to 6.0
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (ID, TestNumber, TestName, TestDescription, TestLengthHours, TestStatus)
VALUES (16, 'SES-2216', 'Cool Name', 'Cool Description', 6.1, 'B');

-- The following /does/ fail. If TestLengthHours is 6.5 or higher, it fails as it should.
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (ID, TestNumber, TestName, TestDescription, TestLengthHours, TestStatus)
VALUES (17, 'SES-2218', 'Cool Name', 'Cool Description', 6.5, 'B');
```

Now, I could just round TestLengthHours to the nearest whole number, but I don't think that would be the the proper way to address this problem.

Another thing that I tried was doing CHECK (TestLengthHours <= 6.0D) like Java does something similar to that, but I was unsuccessful with that attempt as well.

The data type of TestLengthHours is TestLengthHours NUMBER(4)

Comment: In your constraint you use `6.0`, a numeric value, but in the inserts, you use `'6.1'` and `'6.5'`, string values. What's going on there?

Comment: That is an excellent question! I tried removing the apostrophes and ran the code again to no success. I will edit my submission accordingly.

Comment: What's the data type of TestLengthHours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would create `TESTTABLE` with `TestLengthHours number not null` for `TestLengthHours` column, adding `CHECK (TestLengthHours <= 6 )` constraint would be enough. Since '6.1' or '6.5' are string values while 6.1 and 6.5 are numeric

In your case, it seems the data type is `integer` and insertion is rounded( `number` data type would be used instead of `integer` ).

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to respond! I edited my submission to reflect this inaccuracy. Also, replying to your other comment, the data type of TestLengthHours is TestLengthHours(4) I added that to my submission as well.

Comment: @Jackson413 you're welcome but what do you mean by `TestLengthHours(4)`?

Comment: Answering your most recent edit, that is exactly what is wrong! Thank you so much!

Comment: I meant to put TestLengthHours NUMBER(4)

Comment: @jackson413 - `NUMBER(4)` is by default `NUMBER(4,0)`, meaning number with at most four significant digits and ZERO decimals (therefore integer!) It is unfortunate, though, that Oracle first rounds the value to fit the column, and only then applies the constraint. It would make a lot of sense to reverse the operations.... good luck convincing Oracle to change it though.